# What are the authentication options available for the Odata service on MS Dynamics 2015 on prem? or where can I find this info?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I am working on a reporting application which talks to the Odata service in MS Dynamics 2015 on prem. Can anyone point me to where I can find all of the authentication methods available within MS Dynamics 2015 on prem? I have to make the app is able to connect to MS Dynamics regardless of what the customer has set up for authentication within MS Dynamics. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OnPremise you have two options:

1. AD authentication
2. Internet Faced Deployment using claims based authentication

Option 2 relies on ADFS.

How you can setup CRM for these scenarios is described in the implementation guide, which can be downloaded [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45022). (It's in Word document *CRMIGv7_PlanandDeploy.docx*.)

Answer (score 0):

I have not much idea about on prem CRM authentication but you can check out [this](http://jlattimer.blogspot.com/2015/02/soap-only-authentication-using-java.html) link it can be used to perform authentication in CRM on prem as well.

Also there are very good articles and code samples explaining CRM authentication with Android,iOS and Cordova mobile apps on this [blog](http://scaleablesolutions.com/tag/mobile/).You can get an idea from there as well.